# Install WordPress themes in a Google cloud instance

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I'm using a Google Cloud instance and I have set up Apache2, MySQL and PHP (LAMP). 
 I then downloaded and installed WordPress.

However I cannot install themes and plugins via `wp-admin`. WordPress asks me for an FTP user, which I do not have.

Do I really need this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the permissions to 755 and changed the owner of the file and the wp-content folder
For some reason it had not worked before, maybe cache.